# How should I connect my humidifier to my furnace's circuit board?

Tags: furnace, gas

I have ganeralaire 1042 humidifier.it connect direct to transformer . my question is can I rewire to furnace control board. model is hk42fz0222105.just want to be active when heat is on. but I don't know which terminal is for that. any one can help will be appreciated.[image]

Edit: wiring diagram: [image]

hi. my circuit board doesn't have hum terminal, can I connect 1 to com24v ,another connect to w1 is it ok or not? thanks a lot.
hi. thank you so much to answer my question. I will try when I am home. Hopefully it work, thanks again and have a nice day.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: [IOM for your humidifier](http://www.generalfilters.com/cm/dpl/downloads/products/12/1042LH-29_-__REV_B_-_GFI_5144_-_1042LH_Installation_&_Owners_Manual.pdf), for reference, BTW

Answer (score 1):

### Connect to W1, yes

You are correct that you want to hook up the W wire from your humidifier to W1 on your furnace control, along with C to COM and R to R.  This is wiring diagram 6(B) in your humidifier's [installation manual](http://www.generalfilters.com/cm/dpl/downloads/products/12/1042LH-29_-__REV_B_-_GFI_5144_-_1042LH_Installation_&_Owners_Manual.pdf), BTW.